# A function that has been defined cannot be called in the main (C++)

Tags: c++

I am learning about functions in C++, and I am trying to create a small function that swaps two values. However, when I try to call this function in the main, I get the error - "No matching function for call to 'swapfunction'". What am I doing wrong?

Here is the code:

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

void swapfunction (double &x,double &y) {

double z(0);

z=y;
y=x;
x=z;

}


int main() {

int a(0);
int b(1);

swapfunction (a,b);

cout<<"a="<<a<<endl;
cout<<"b="<<b<<endl;

}
```

Comment: You should probably change `int a(0);` to `double a(0);` (same for `b`). A `double` reference isn't the same as a `int` reference.

Comment: What are you trying to do with `int a(0);` and `int b(1);`?

Comment: @element11 These are normal and syntactically OK initializers.

Comment: Ah ok! Thank you. @element11 I am trying to see if the function works. Maybe there is an easier way of doing it?

Comment: It works by changing the int to double. Thank you very much

Comment: @πάντα ῥεῖ I cant say I have ever seen c++ variables declared like that, although after a couple of google searches, you are correct. Good to know. Cant say i would declare variables like that, but thank you.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`swapfunction`'s parameters are *references* to `doubles`, which means that the arguments have to be `double` *objects*. A `double&` reference cannot refer to an `int` object.

If the arguments were `double` rather than `double&`, the call would be legal, and the values of `a` and `b` would be implicitly converted from `int` to `double` -- but then the function couldn't update `a` and `b`.

You need to define objects of type `double` to pass to the function.